# c++ polymorphism and virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, polymorphism

Is it possible to call the virtual function foo( int ) from B without using what is done in comment ?

```
class A {
public: 

    virtual void foo ( char * ) {
    }

    virtual void foo ( int ) {
    }
};

class B : public A {
public:

    void foo ( char * ) {
    }

    //void foo ( int i ) {
    //  
    //  A::foo(i);
    //}
};

B b;
b.foo(123); // cannot convert argument 1 from 'int' to 'char *'
```

Comment: Please fix the indenting..... the declaration of `virtual void foo(int)` on first glance appears to be the body of `virtual void foo(char *)`.  Compilers may not care about odd formatting, but humans do....

Comment: @AndreKostur FWIW, the weird indent of `foo` overloads was introduced by an editor, not by the OP.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. The problem here is that the function `B::foo(char*)` *hides* the name of the inherited function `A::foo(int)`, but you can bring it back into scope of `B` with a `using` declaration:

```
class B : public A {
public:

    void foo ( char * ) {
    }

    using A::foo;
};
```